# Springsteen was charged with "consuming alcohol in an enclosed area"

Tags: united-states, alcohol

Bruce Springsteen received  including DWI and "consuming alcohol in an enclosed area" (the word "closed" is also used) in November 2020 in Gateway National Recreation Area in New Jersey. I searched for those phrases and for National Park Service regulations related to alcohol and was unable to find an explanation.

I'd like to see a link to the relevant law and have an explanation of what constitutes a closed or enclosed area in this context and the motivation for this restriction. This seems odd to me because, in my opinion, restricting the consumption of alcohol in public, *outside* of enclosed places, is the familiar case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The area is "closed" (not open), or "restricted" to alcohol consumption. [Here is a memo](https://www.nps.gov/policy/PolMemos/PM_07-02.pdf) reminding of alcohol restrictions, noting [36 CFR 2.35](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/36/2.35) which states that

> The superintendent may close all or a portion of a public use area or
> public facility within a park area to the consumption of alcoholic
> beverages and/or to the possession of a bottle, can or other
> receptacle containing an alcoholic beverage that is open, or that has
> been opened, or whose seal is broken or the contents of which have
> been partially removed.

This was done in the case of the area, apparently a few years earlier (i,e, it used to be allowed and there was a policy change). The [Gateway Nt'l Park website](https://www.nps.gov/gate/learn/management/lawsandpolicies.htm) states that "Alcoholic beverages at Sandy Hook are prohibited", as are a bunch of other things.

The motivation is part of the regulation, that the superintendent determined that

> (A) The consumption of an alcoholic beverage or the possession of an
> open container of an alcoholic beverage would be inappropriate
> considering other uses of the location and the purpose for which it is
> maintained or established; or
>
> (B) Incidents of aberrant behavior related to the consumption of
> alcoholic beverages are of such magnitude that the diligent
> application of the authorities in this section and §§ 1.5 and 2.34 of
> this chapter, over a reasonable time period, does not alleviate the
> problem.

Comment: Ah, so the closure is the restriction itself rather than being a physical one. So "enclosure" is probably a poorly chosen word by a lay person.